# How to check the input contain non digits characters?

Tags: c

Hi everyone I'm new to C, I have a question about how to check the input whether contain non-digital characters.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
 char arraySize;
 scanf("%c",&arraySize);
 if(!isdigit(arraySize)){
  printf("BADINPUT\n");
 }else{
  return 0;
 }
}
```

When I run my code, I Inputed `xy4` and It `printf` BADINPUT. However, when I Iputted `4xyz` It did not `printf` BADINPUT. It seems like only read first charcter and check whether `isdigit` or not.

How can I change my code so that when I Inputted `4xyz` It will also be BADINPUT?

Comment: your `scanf("%c",&arraySize);` is only picking up one char, I might thick that you wanted to read the string size first, then read the input string

Answer (score 2):

You are giving ! before isdigit() . Thats why is getting wrong output.

Your declaration of var name is worst. YOu can refer bello code ->>

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
     int main(){
            char input_character;
            scanf("%c",&input_character);
            if(isdigit(input_character)){
                printf("BADINPUT\n");
            }else{
                  printf("\nGood Input\n");
            }
      return 0; 
        }
```

Comment: your code does not solve OP's problem. He wants to check non-digit character in a string, not only one character. Also, OP wants to print `BADINPUT` in case it contains non-digit character. You code does exactly opposite for even single character

Comment: Thank you for answer, but that's not what I asking for

Comment: @KanzakiAriaEcho I didnt get your question??? Do you want to check for whole char array? Then I will give you solution for the char array. You have to check each char until '\0' .

Comment: I wanna digit only not like 45x

Answer (score 1):

isdigit(c) is a function in C which can be used to check if the passed character is a digit or not.To check  non-digital characters in a string loop statements are required.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[]="4xyz";
    int count =0;
    for (i=0; str[i]!= '\0'; i++) 
    { 
      if (isdigit(str[i]) != 0) 
      {
          count++;
      }
    if(count)
    {
        printf("BADINPUT\n");
    }else
    {
        printf("GOODINPUT\n");
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to take a character array as input because you are passing in "xyz" or "4xyz", which is a string (collection of characters) but not a single character. For that, change `char arraySize;` to `char arraySize[MAX_SIZE_OF_THE_ARRAY];`.

You take a character array input just like a string, using `%s` and without passing the address i.e. without `&` .

Then after that, you need to run a for loop to check if any of the characters in the character array is a Digit, if you find even a single digit in the character array, you print "BADINPUT". And if not even a single-digit exists in the char array, you print "GOOD INPUT".

So the final code should look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 1000
// can take any value, i.e. the maximum size of the array

int main() {
  // you can also assign a more suitable name to the array.
  char arraySize[MAX];
  scanf("%s", arraySize);
  int i;
  for (i=0; arraySize[i]!='\0'; ++i) {
    if (isdigit(arraySize[i])) {
      printf("BADINPUT\n");
      return 0;      
    }
  }
  printf("GOOD INPUT\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are reading just the first character in your scanf call. isdigit only checks for a character. You can do something like this

```
    int i,flag = 0;
    char * c = (char *)malloc(10);
    memset(c, 0, 10);

    scanf("%s", c);

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (c[i]!= '\0' && !isdigit(c[i])) {
           printf("BAD VALUE");
           flag++;
           break;
       }
   }

    if(flag == 0)
          printf("Good Value");
```

Comment: prefer using `isdigit` rather than checking the ascii code as you would not know what would be the character encoding.

Comment: I changed the answer since OP also used isdigit() , but isdigit() expects ascii characters right

Comment: [specifications for isdigit](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/isdigit.html) seem to differ on your assumption

Comment: Quote : The isdigit() function shall test whether c is a character of class digit in the **program's current locale**